# Basic Player/Character Structure

Tags: c#, beginner

While the experience is limited in C#, it is not in OOP generally. While the `Beginner`-tag is used, relentless, harsh (but constructive) feedback is still wanted. It is more for you to get a grasp of the experience in C# so far.

*Would you want this code in your next AAA game title? If not, what are the problem(s)?* That being said, the purpose is not to write perfect code, it should be good, acceptable is not acceptable.

The idea is to have a `Character` that in turn declares and initializes its fields. For now they are:

- `Level`, the character´s current level.
- `ExpCur`, how much experience is achieved on this level.
- `ExpTnl`, the experience needed to advance a level.
- `Attributes`, a `Dictionary` storing the two existing attributes, `Offensive` and `Defensive` (they can be found in `AttributeConstants.cs`) with the name as the keys.
- `AttributePoints`, how many remaining points can be spent on an `Attribute`.

To those fields there are some helpers, nothing should directly be exposed outside of `Character.cs`, if a change to an instance `Character` is needed `Character.cs` should provide a mutator of some sort for that value.

**Character.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Character
{
    class Character
    {
        public int Level { get; private set; }
        public int ExpCur { get; private set; }
        public int ExpTnl { get; private set; }

        private Dictionary<string, Attribute> Attributes = new Dictionary<string, Attribute>();
        public int AttributePoints { get; private set; }

        public Character (int level)
        {
            Level = (level > 0 ) ? level : 1;
            ExpCur = 0;
            ExpTnl = 100 * level;

            foreach (String s in AttributeConstants.AttributeNames)
            {
                Attributes.Add(s, new Attribute (AttributeConstants.DefaultValue));
            }

            AttributePoints = (level - 1) * AttributeConstants.AttributePointsPerLevel;
        }

        public int AddExp (int exp)
        {
            int curLevel = Level;
            ExpCur += exp;

            while (ExpCur >= ExpTnl)
            {
                ExpCur -= ExpTnl;
                ExpTnl = 100 * Level;
                Level++;
                AttributePoints += AttributeConstants.AttributePointsPerLevel;
            }

            return Level - curLevel;
        }

        public AttributeUnmodifiable GetAttribute (string name)
        {
            return new AttributeUnmodifiable(Attributes[name].Value, Attributes[name].Modifiers);
        }

        public void IncAttribute (string name)
        {
            if (AttributePoints > 0)
            {
                AttributePoints--;
                Attributes[name].Inc ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AttributeConstants.cs**

This class purpose is to gather all constants for attributes. So that there are no hidden constants all over the place.

```
namespace Character
{
    public class AttributeConstants
    {
        internal static readonly string[] AttributeNames = {
            "Offensive",
            "Defensive",
        };

        internal static readonly string[] AttributeDescriptions = {
            "Your damage. Lorem Ipsum...",
            "Your defense. Lorem Ipsum...",
        };

        internal static readonly int DefaultValue = 5;
        internal static readonly int AttributePointsPerLevel = 2;
    }
}
```

**Attribute.cs**

A simply attribute that stores it (Base)`Value` as well as a list of `AttributeModifiers` with both a flat (`BuffValue`) value as well as a coefficient, to get the total value one adds the base with all the buff values then multiply by its coefficient.

One idea here to optimize is to also store a private copy of both its total `BuffValue` as well as the total coefficient. That will give two more fields, and slower execution on adding and removing `AttributeModifiers`. While it will be faster to perform lookups.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Character
{
    class Attribute
    {
        public int Value { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, AttributeModifier> Modifiers { get; private set; }

        public Attribute (int value)
        {
            Value = value;
            Modifiers = new Dictionary<string, AttributeModifier>();
        }        

        public void Inc ()
        {
            Value++;
        }

        public void Dec()
        {
            Value--;
        }

        public void AddAttributeModifier (string name, int constant, float coefficient)
        {
            Modifiers.Add(name, new AttributeModifier(constant, coefficient));
        }

        public void RemoveAttributeModifier (string name)
        {
            Modifiers.Remove(name);
        }

        public int GetBuffValue()
        {
            int buff = 0;

            foreach (AttributeModifier m in Modifiers.Values)
            {
                buff += m.Constant;
            }

            return buff;
        }

        public float GetCoefficient()
        {
            float coefficient = 0.0f;

            foreach (AttributeModifier m in Modifiers.Values)
            {
                coefficient += m.Coefficient;
            }

            return coefficient;
        }

        public int GetTotalValue()
        {
            return (int)((Value + GetBuffValue()) * (1+GetCoefficient()));
        }
    }
}
```

**AttributeUnmodifiable.cs**

Immutable version of `Attribute`, to make sure that nothing can be changed outside of `Character`.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Character
{
    class AttributeUnmodifiable
    {
        public int Value { get; private set; }
        public Dictionary<string, AttributeModifier> Modifiers { get; private set; }

        public AttributeUnmodifiable(int value, Dictionary<string, AttributeModifier> modifiers)
        {
            Value = value;
            Modifiers = modifiers;
        }

        public int GetBuffValue()
        {
            int buff = 0;

            foreach (AttributeModifier m in Modifiers.Values)
            {
                buff += m.Constant;
            }

            return buff;
        }

        public float GetCoefficient()
        {
            float coefficient = 0.0f;

            foreach (AttributeModifier m in Modifiers.Values)
            {
                coefficient += m.Coefficient;
            }

            return coefficient;
        }

        public int GetTotalValue()
        {
            return (int)((Value + GetBuffValue()) * (1+GetCoefficient()));
        }
    }
}
```

**AttributeModifier.cs**

```
namespace Character
{
    class AttributeModifier
    {
        public int Constant { get; private set; }
        public float Coefficient { get; private set; }

        public AttributeModifier(int constant, float coefficient)
        {
            Constant = constant;
            Coefficient = coefficient;
        }
    }
}
```

**Test.cs**

A (very) simple test to execute the code.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Character c = new Character(5);

        System.Console.WriteLine ("Level: " + c.Level + " ( " + c.ExpCur + " / " + c.ExpTnl + " ) ");

        foreach (string s in AttributeConstants.AttributeNames )
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine (s + ": " + c.GetAttribute(s).GetTotalValue() + " ( ( " + c.GetAttribute(s).Value + " + " + c.GetAttribute(s).GetBuffValue() + " ) * " + c.GetAttribute(s).GetCoefficient() + " )");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine ("Attribute Points: " + c.AttributePoints);
    }
}
```

Any feedback, be it just one line that could be changed is both wanted and appreciated.

**Update(s) from comments:**

> You talk about optimizing things (attribute values), as well as the
>   need to make sure that "nothing should directly be exposed".

Optimizing isn't that much of a concern know. I will know later on if that is needed, for now it is more the architectural part, is it good code praxis what I've done?

> Are you primarily looking for review of the code's performance? Or security? > Or standards compliance?

Standard compliance.

> Also, is this Character interacting with any other classes? Or are we
>   to assume this is a closed system consisting only of the code given?

The character should only interact from the way the `Test.cs` is using it. There will no sorts of reflection or its like. Other systems will access it for information. They will always have to go trough `Character.cs` to change its values, after its rules.

**Update(s) from answers:**

> Are Attributes things or values of things?

Solved, it is now more clear what they are(will) be used for in the code.

> One man's Attribute is another man's AttributeUnmodifiable...
>   Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

They are both solved by having an an `abstract class Stat` backing them up now.

> C# is not Java: Use first class properties and leave the getters at home!

This code is being translated from Java... that obvious? :(

Comment: You talk about optimizing things (attribute values), as well as the need to make sure that "_nothing should directly be exposed_"..  Are you primarily looking for review of the code's performance? Or security,? Or standards compliance?
Also, is this `Character` interacting with any other classes?  Or are we to assume this is a _closed system_ consisting only of the code given?

Comment: @Tersosauros I hope I added some clarifications now for it. If there still are questions or areas that are unclear feel free to ask for further clarification.

Comment: Is `AttributeConstants` _just_ for testing purposes, or would this be how you intend to store these values permanently?

Comment: Permanently, or well, they might be moved to a some sort of local DB.

Comment: Well, if they *might be moved* to **anywhere** else, I would recommend you encapsulate this with a little more OO.  Something like an `IAttributeProvider` interface, which you can then have a simple `internal` *implementation* like the current one **and** a more complicated `DatabaseAttributeProviderImpl` or similar for when your solution architecture (inevitably) becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Are `Attribute`s *things* or *values of things*?

In your current naming/abstraction/etcetera, it seems an `Attribute` is simply an encapsulated integer value (albeit with some in-built formulas attached in the form of `Modifier`'s).  It strikes me as odd that an `Attribute` doesn't have a Name, for example.  (Hence why it seems more like an encapsulation of integer than an abstraction of a game `Character`s' attribute.)

I think fields such as Name, Description, etc could be added to `Attribute`.  (It is currently unclear what the `AttributeDescriptions` in your `AttributeConstants` class are for, IMHO.)

---

### One man's `Attribute` is another man's `AttributeUnmodifiable`...

First of all, let me just rant for a moment... `AttributeUnmodifiable`!?  Surely under any [reasonable naming convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) this should be called an `UnmodifiableAttribute`?  End class names with a noun.  Phew! Okay </rant>.

It seems to me that what you are *representing* with an `Attribute` changes slightly.  In particular, inside `Character` you essentially want `Attribute`s to be *mutable*, while outside you want them immutable (or "*unmodifiable*", as your code puts it).

Given that (as stated in your edits) you're not concerned about reflection/introspection/reverse engineering/other security issues.. It would make more sense to use an **interface** to accomplish this immutability.

If you had an `IAttribute` interface, with all of your public properties and methods defined, and then an `Attribute`, `MutableAttribute` or even `AttributeImpl` class *implementing* that interface - you could make all of the public methods and properties of `Character` return `IAttribute`s.  This way, `Character` can internally know about the `internal` public details implemented by an `Attribute` and outsiders only see the (immutable/unmodifiable) [*mask*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290336/what-happens-when-we-create-an-object-of-interface/17290410#17290487).

---

### [Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)

Even if you elect not to create an `IAttribute` interface, it still seems that there's a **lot** of repeated code shared between `Attribute` and `AttributeUnmodifiable`^.  For example, the `GetBuffValue`, `GetCoefficient` and `GetTotalValue` methods have ********identical******** implementations in each class.  This makes maintenance and upkeep **far** more time consuming (as code changes now have to occur at two points).

<sup>^ Note:  Making that `IAttribute` interface and making an `AbstractAttribute` are **neither** mutually exclusive, nor co-dependant.  you can do either one, or both (or neither, if you want).</sup>

For example, let's say some astute programmer pointed out that **you should be using [double-point precision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/678hzkk9.aspx)** for the accumulator variable in `GetCoefficient`.  At the moment, you would have to make this change in the `GetCoefficient` implementation in `Attribute`, test it, etc, then make the *same* change **again** in `AttributeUnmodifiable` (and test it again, etc).

**Enter `AbstractAttribute`**

Rather than have all of this repeated code laying around, you could [implement it once (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), and then have `Attribute` and **`UnmodifiableAttribute`** (aka `AttributeUnmodifiable`) [`extend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) `AbstractAttribute` to get the (single, easy to maintain) implementation.

---

### C# is not Java: Use first class properties and leave the getters at home!

While we're on the subject of the `GetBuffValue`, `GetCoefficient` and `GetTotalValue` *methods*... Let me just have another little rant regarding [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  C# is **NOT** Java, [C# has first class properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29#C.23) (*i.e.* a property in C# isn't *just* a method with a certain word at the start of the name).  Java-style [*getters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method#Java_example) are NOT the way we do things in C#! </rant>

Instead of:

> ```
> public float GetCoefficient()
> {
>      ... getter code...
> }
> ```

(Which, as indicated by the `()` brackets at the end of the name, declares a **method**.)

Try using a property (without the `Get` at the front):

```
 public float Coefficient
 {
      get
      {
           ... getter code...
      }
 }
```

The same goes for `GetBuffValue` and `GetTotalValue` too.

In general, if something is just an enquiry about an objects state, and doesn't require any arguments and will not change the object's state - use a property (not a method).

---

### Don't return state from setters, <sup><sub>particularly in a language with first class exceptions</sub></sup>

Lastly, I've noticed that the `AddExp` method of your `Character` class is **returning** a value (that value being the current level, indicating if the increase in XP led to a level-up).
As pointed out [over here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309068/why-is-chaining-setters-unconventional#309074), such a thing violates [the principle of Command–query Separation (CQS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

If a method that is responsible for mutating state (a *setter* in Java parlance), ever **needs** to return something - then usually that is indicative of an error occurring. In C#, we have Exceptions for this - so setters should *really* **NEVER** need to return.

I understand the need for the game engine (or whomever is *using* the `Character` instance) to be **notified** when a level-up occurs, however, there are other (better) ways of doing this (which don't violate [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)).

The [pub/sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) or ["Publish/Subscribe" pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649664.aspx) comes to mind here.  (The `Character` can notify subscribers of a '*level-up*' `Event`, etc).  This way, the logic to detect a level-up *lives in one place* (`character`), rather than needing to be **everywhere** that `AddExp` is called.

Comment: I don't have time to go through it all now, I read it. This is the feedback I wanted. Two fun things, I thought I overused Properties, I thought that is  where the *attack* were going to be aimed at. Second, I asked myself how hard I would be criticalled by the "Attribute vs AttributeUnmod...". I just did not know a proper way to solve the later. Again thanks. Will get back with more substance to my comment later this day.